# Titanium Paypal integration for Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I'm learning Titanium for mobile development. Currently, I am trying to learn Paypal usage through Titanium programming. I have the following test code.

```
var ppButton = Ti.Paypal.createPaypalButton({
    width: 294,
    height: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    appId: "APP_80W294485PS19543T",
    buttonStyle: Ti.Paypal.BUTTON_294x43,
    paypalEnvironment: Ti.Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX,
    feePaidByReceiver: false,
    transactionType: Ti.Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_DONATION,
    enableShipping: false,
    payment: {
        amount: 1.50,
        tax: 0.00,
        shipping: 0.00,
        currency: "USD",
        recipient: "fname_1343709942_per@gmail.com",
        itemDescription: "Donation",
        merchantName: "American Red Cross"
    }
});
```

But the application crashes on launching giving force close error.
Can anybody point out the problem and suggest the solution? I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try [This](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/780?752585722)

this is a Module and provided by Appecelerator.
Download [This](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/780?752585722) and use this work fine.